# Node Js | Cant POST FORM appended JavaScript Values to backend / wrong values

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need your help, im slowly getting frustrated at a problem i have. So lets start shall we?

Basicly i want to POST Data from a Front End to my (Express) Backend with the small diffrence that one of the values comes from an JS Function (rich text editor / [editor.js](https://editorjs.io/)) and has to be put into the FORM before its being posted. Im doing this via jQuery with: $('form').submit....
and at the end of the anonymous function i use $(this).append(...). Now if i post the data it dosent output what it should be on my backend. when i check on the front end with console.log() the values everything looks fine, i also convert the json from the text editor to an string with JSON.stringify

So heres the code:

Front End:

```
    $("form").submit(function(){
    var textBlock = ''
    editor.save().then((outputData) => { //the outputData is an JSON
        var outputString = JSON.stringify(outputData) 
        textBlock = outputString 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error: ' + error)
    }) 
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="textBody" value="' + textBlock + '"/>')
    return true
})
```

Result in the backend:

```
  '[object Object]',
  '[object Object]',
  '[object Object]',
  '[object Object]'
```

Pls help ╯︿╰

Comment: Honestly it's pretty hard to track what is happening without the server side part of the code. Maybe it's not parsed correctly there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am totally wrong here but could it be that you are sending/receiving the right data but it is actually the print on the server that is misleading you.

If you print the code on the backend using this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))
```

Comment: Also remember to look at your network tab in the browser dev tools. If you see the correct data is being sent you can forget about the frontend and focus on the backend.

Comment: hello, i tried what you told me but now i only get an "{". this is what the <input> tag looks like: <input type="hidden" name="textBody" value="{"time":1628945417389,"blocks":[{"id":"UCCDTnbRaI","type":"paragraph","data":{"text":"esffes"}}],"version":"2.22.2"}">

Comment: when i also post the url string manually it looks like that the string didnt really survived the post process. I now manually posted the <input> string manually with postman to my server and this came out: "{\"time\":1628945417389,\"blocks\":[{\"id\":\"UCCDTnbRaI\",\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"data\":{\"text\":\"esffes\"}}],\"version\":\"2.22.2\"}".

Comment: It looks like all {} are replaced with backslashes. I dunno why, i also should mention that this is an multipart-form